# Digital modelling of circuits with diode (i.e. guitar distortion)

Tags: distortion

For the last few days I was struggling to come up with an idea how to model a guitar overdrive effect which works in realtime. One of the simplest circuit diagrams that produce it looks as follows:
[image]

The plot depicts output for 400Hz 1V sine wave at the input.

Normally I'd derive transfer function of the circuit, but in this case I think it cannot be done because diode is a nonlinear component and transfer functions exist only for linear differential equations. 
Nevertheless the program I used for the simulation (Falstad Circuit Simulator) generates valid solution somehow... I was thinking of maybe deriving differential equation for the whole circuit and then applying some numerical scheme to find the solution - this however could be easily become unstable and it would be considerably harder for me to analyze. Are there some tools that could readily generate equations (be it difference, differential or transfer functions) for such circuit?

**EDIT**
I already tried with waveshaping. I came up with an idea to find coefficients of a polynomial to generate best fitting waveshaping function using a genetic algorithm. The algorithm converged nicely, but unfortunately, using a polynomial as the function model (tried up to 5th order) I cannot get anything that would resemble the desired output waveform.

Comment: Google search is your friend there. Aalto University LC has some good Open Access papers you could check ... as like [Dias de Paiva, Rafael : _Circuit modeling studies related to guitars and audio processing_](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/handle/123456789/11192) (check "publication 4" as for an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you treat the diodes as having memoryless non-linear volt-amp characteristics and treat the capacitor as linear and having memory, you can use [Euler's backward method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to represent the capacitors and everything else are static Kirchoff equations (with some nonlinearity, you need to represent the back-to-back diodes accurately -  the standard diode equation might not be good enough).

---

okay, first let's deal with the parallel diodes.  a single diode volt-amp characteristic is

$$ i_D(t) = I_D \left( e^{\frac{q \ v_D(t)}{k T}} -1 \right) $$

$v_D(t)>0$ means *forward bias* of the diode and a significant current $i_D(t)>0$ flows.  when $v_D(t)<0$, it is *reversed biased* and the most current that will flow is $i_D(t)=-I_D<0$ .  $I_D$ is the reverse saturation current and is very tiny.

$q$ is the elementary charge (sometimes called the "electron charge", but is a positive number), $k$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $T$ (in this section) is the absolute temperature of the PN junction of the diode (about 293K).  $\frac{kT}{q}$ is a voltage about $\tfrac{1}{40}$ volt.  when $v_D(t)=\frac{kT}{q}$ the forward diode current is still approximately $+I_D$, which is extremely small.  the exponential curve doesn't visibly kick in until $v_D(t) \approx 25 \cdot \frac{kT}{q} = 0.65$ volt.

keeping the polarities defined in the same direction but reversing the diode results in

$$ i_D(t) = -I_D \left(e^{\frac{-q \ v_D(t)}{k T}} -1\right) $$

putting the two in parallel (assuming the same $I_D$), the volt-amp description is

$$\begin{align}
i_D(t) & = I_D \left(e^{\frac{q \ v_D(t)}{k T}} -1\right) - I_D \left(e^{\frac{-q \ v_D(t)}{k T}} -1\right) \\
\\
& = I_D \left(e^{\frac{q \ v_D(t)}{k T}} - e^{\frac{-q \ v_D(t)}{k T}}\right) \\
\\
& = 2 I_D \sinh\left(\frac{q \ v_D(t)}{k T}\right)  \\
\end{align} $$

inverting the volt-amp equation:

$$\begin{align}
 v_D(t) &= \frac{kT}{q}\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{i_D(t)}{2 I_D} \right) \\
        &= \frac{kT}{q}\ln\left(\frac{i_D(t)+\sqrt{i_D(t)^2 + (2I_D)^2}}{2 I_D} \right) \\
\end{align} $$

probably the diodes have some contact resistance, and there is a fudge factor $\eta \approx 1$ or $2$ scaling the voltage, which will make the equation look like

$$  v_D(t) = \frac{\eta kT}{q}\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{i_D(t)}{2 I_D} \right) + R_D \, i_D(t) $$

now, probably, rather than trying to find (from measured curves) the values of $I_D$ and $R_D$ and, the $\eta\frac{kT}{q}$ factor, you will probably just have a power series to represent the diodes.  since the equation has odd-symmetry, your power series will have only odd-order terms.

$$ i_D(t) = a_1 v_D(t) + a_3 (v_D(t))^3 + a_5 (v_D(t))^5 + \dots $$

you might not even need the inner terms and might be able to get away with just two terms, like

$$ i_D(t) = a_1 v_D(t) + \dots a_9 (v_D(t))^9 $$

ignoring terms in between.  this will make your computations cheaper.

that's all i want to say about the diodes.  you will have some memoryless model for the diode pair:

$$ i_D(t) = f\big( \, v_D(t) \,\big) $$
or the inverse function
$$ v_D(t) = g\big( \, i_D(t) \,\big) $$

that you will need to nail down a decent approximation of.

---

Euler's backward method:

the capacitor has fundamental volt-amp characteristics:

$$\begin{align}
i_C(t) &= C \frac{d \, v_C(t)}{dt} \\
       &= C \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{v_C(t) - v_C(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t} \\
\\
       &\approx C \frac{v_C(t) - v_C(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t} \qquad \text{for very small } \Delta t \\
\end{align} $$

or looking at it from the perspective of capacitor voltage

$$\begin{align}
v_C(t) &= \frac{1}{C} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} i_C(u) \, du \\
       &= \frac{1}{C} \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t-\Delta t} i_C(u) \, du + \int\limits_{t-\Delta t}^{t} i_C(u) \, du \right) \\
       &= v_C(t-\Delta t) + \frac{1}{C} \int\limits_{t-\Delta t}^{t} i_C(u) \, du  \\
       &\approx v_C(t-\Delta t) + \frac{1}{C} \int\limits_{t-\Delta t}^{t} i_C(t) \, du \\
\\
       &= v_C(t-\Delta t) + \frac{1}{C} i_C(t) \, \Delta t  \qquad \text{for very small } \Delta t \\
\end{align} $$

both approximations say exactly the same thing and demonstrate the meaning we have when we differentiate between **memoryless** devices and those **with memory**.  the ideal diode is memoryless because, in the ideal, the relationship between the voltage and current at its terminals depends **only** on their values **at the present**.  the ideal capacitor is a device *with* memory because the relationship between the *present* voltage and current at its terminals depends on a voltage the capacitor remembers from the very recent past.

so let the tiny *"differential"* time $\Delta t$ be our *sampling period* or $\Delta t = \frac{1}{f_\text{s}}$.  then we need evaluate $t$ at only integer sampling periods:

$$ t = n \cdot \Delta t $$

then

$$\begin{align}
v_C(t) &= v_C(t-\Delta t) + \frac{\Delta t}{C} i_C(t) \\
\\
v_C(n \Delta t) &= v_C(n \Delta t-\Delta t) + \frac{\Delta t}{C} i_C(n \Delta t) \\
\\
 &= v_C((n-1) \Delta t) + \frac{\Delta t}{C} i_C(n \Delta t) \\
\\
v_C[n] &= v_C[n-1] + \frac{\Delta t}{C} i_C[n] \\
\end{align}$$

at a specific time $t$, for every capacitor, you can represent that capacitor as a (briefly) constant voltage source (the previous sample's voltage) in series with a resistor having value $R_C=\tfrac{\Delta t}{C}$.  and we can express that voltage source in series with a resistor as a **Thevenin source** having its own **Norton equivalent** whenever it is convenient to express it as such.  (it **is** convenient to do that for the 470 pF cap in the feedback path.)

let $C_1$=100nF, $R_1$=1K, $C_2$=470pF, $R_2$=10K, assuming the op-amp is ideal, the load resistance is not salient.  the op-amp in negative feedback maintains virtual equality across its input terminals.  the current flowing through $R_1$ into $C_1$ is

$$\begin{align}
i_1(t) &= \frac{1}{R_1}(v_\text{in}(t) - v_{C1}(t)) \\
       &= \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}(t) - v_{C1}(t-\Delta t)) \\
\\
i_1[n] &= \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}[n] - v_{C1}[n-1]) \\
\end{align}$$

now the feedback current must equal $i_1(t)$.  here, you want to express the source/resistance model of $C_2$ as a Norton equivalent.  then the two diodes, the 10K resistor $R_2$, **and** the Norton resistance ($\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_2}$ are in parallel with the Norton current source of $v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t}$) must be placed in parallel and an aggregate volt-amp characteristic must be known.  you want voltage as a function of current.

$$ v_D(t) = g\big( \, i_D(t) \, \big) $$

that is the volt-amp characteristic of two diodes in parallel with two known resistances.  so the feedback current will be divided into two currents, the known Norton equivalent current from the known $C_2$ voltage of the previous sample period and whatever flows into your non-linear device which is two diodes in parallel with two resistances.

$$ i_1(t) = -v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} + i_D(t) $$
or

$$\begin{align}
i_D(t) &= i_1(t) + v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \\
       &= \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}(t) - v_{C1}(t-\Delta t)) + v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
v_D(t) &= g\big( \, i_D(t) \, \big) \\
       &= g\big( i_1(t) + v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \big) \\
       &= g\bigg( \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}(t) - v_{C1}(t-\Delta t)) + v_{C2}(t-\Delta t)\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \bigg) \\
\end{align}$$

in discrete time, it's

$$v_D[n] = g\bigg( \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}[n] - v_{C1}[n-1]) + v_{C2}[n-1]\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \bigg) $$

and the output is

$$\begin{align}
v_\text{out}[n] &= v_D[n] + v_\text{in}[n] \\
                &= g\bigg( i_1[n] + v_{C2}[n-1]\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \bigg) + v_\text{in}[n] \\
                &= g\bigg( \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}[n] - v_{C1}[n-1]) + v_{C2}[n-1]\tfrac{C_2}{\Delta t} \bigg) + v_\text{in}[n] \\
\end{align}$$

and you must update your two capacitor states for the next sampling period:

$$\begin{align}
v_{C1}[n] &= v_{C1}[n-1] + \frac{\Delta t}{C_1} i_1[n] \\
          &= v_{C1}[n-1] + \frac{\Delta t}{C_1} \left( \frac{1}{R_1+\tfrac{\Delta t}{C_1}}(v_\text{in}[n] - v_{C1}[n-1]) \right) \\
\\
v_{C2}[n] &= v_D[n] \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean to first represent the whole circuit as a differential equation of voltage in time and then discretize it using euler scheme? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: only the capacitors need be described by a differential equation, which can then be discretized with the simplest Euler method.  i'll try to lay out some equations into my answer in a bit.

Comment: Forward Euler is the *worst* solver you can use, especially for strong non-linearities like those used in a distortion circuit.

Comment: depends on the sample rate, Jazz. forward Euler doesn't require iterations and makes for efficient code.  and looking at the circuit, with parallel diodes **and** a parallel 10K resistor, i might guess that the non-linear function of those three memoryless devices in parallel will be reasonably mild.  i would bet that, picking two good coefficients that: 

$$ i_D(t) = \left(a_1 + a_9 \bigg( \Big( \big( v_D(t) \big)^2 \Big)^2 \bigg)^2 \right) v_D(t) $$ 

will model the nonlinearity pretty well for the sake of capturing the sound of the given circuit.

Comment: looks like the way this is going, it might be Euler's **backward** method.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, the problem with forward Euler is not the sampling rate. It can be shown that the accumulation of error grows faster than the improvement of convergence in general. So decreasing the integration step actually makes the result worse after a certain point. And that point is usually well before you get a good result.

Comment: no, Jazz.  decreasing $\Delta t$ makes the result better.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, do you mean decreasing the stepsize makes things worse because of **numerical** issues??  (i haven't been worrying about quantization errors in this answer.)  $ v_C(t) - v_C(t - \Delta t) $ gets closer and closer to zero as $\Delta t \to 0$.  i can certainly imagine that the difference might round to zero when it is necessary that $ v_C(t) \ne v_C(t - \Delta t) $

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, read the last paragraph here: http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~bard/numerics/node3.html

Comment: so what about word-width?  considering what happens in a modern processor?  wider word width is independent of the size of $\Delta t$.  i understand that quantization errors appear.  specifically with the model above, regarding the value of $i_1[n]$ and that will be "*amplified*" with the non-linearity where the slopes are steep.  but that non-linearity is more of an $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$ function, not a $\sinh(x)$.  at around $x\approx 0$, it's gonna be pretty linear and this simulation of an op-amp circuit will be as stable as the op-amp circuit is.

Comment: Sure, you're free to ignore decades of research on numerical methods and do your engineering stuff. I'm tired of arguing. For everyone else, the presentation I've linked to above is a great source for understanding robust integration of ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Jazz, i've done virtually exactly this in plugin DSP code.  almost the same circuit (but i think we also tossed in some 2nd harmonic distortion).  i am quite aware of numerical methods and i am quite aware of robust simulation of diff eqs.  the thing is, we're just trying to capture a sound that some, sorta crude, distortion circuit does.  especially at 96 kHz modeling a capacitor as $$ v_C[n] = v_C[n-1] + \frac{1}{f_\text{s}C} i_C[n] $$ works **very** well.  i've even done this for a 56K which was 24-bit fixed.  and the non-linearity was 5th order or less.

Comment: as i recall, since the DSP works only with dimensionless numbers (and finite-precision, which is a legitimate worry), how i modeled every capacitor was with  $$ \frac{v_C[n]}{V_\text{ref}} = \frac{v_C[n-1]}{V_\text{ref}} + \frac{\tfrac{I_\text{ref}}{V_\text{ref}}}{f_\text{s}C} \frac{i_C[n]}{I_\text{ref}} $$  particularly with the 56K, i had to choose the reference voltage $V_\text{ref}$ and current $I_\text{ref}$ well so that the values in the DSP were numerically meaningful

Comment: Great for you. None of that makes forward Euler a good method. You can get *much* better result with *less* effort, and also more stability and greater versatility. Scientific evidence for the quality of the approximation of a solution and numerical stability are obviously way overrated. But like I said, I'm not willing to take this discussion any further. Your views are just not compatible with mine, as we've found often enough. I've tried it with rigour and logic before, without success. So please forgive me for not trying again, as you're not trying either.

Comment: you know what makes it a good method?  simplicity and efficiency in the code.  i never represented the diode curves exactly either (because i wanted to use a finite power series).  and it **still** distorted in a manner similar to the circuit i was emulating **and** i never did any of that unnecessary "zero-delay" feedback stuff.  no multiple iterations with the Newton-Raphson method.  just a 5th-order power series.  and a **single** pass through the sample processing code.

Comment: i mean what good does it do to nail the diode equation exactly when, in manufacturing, the diodes all vary anyway?

Comment: Why do you assume that I am  suggesting using an implicit method that would require root finding? Second order explicit methods are already vastly better than forward Euler. And this is not about the parameters of the diode but about the character of the solution. Those are very different things. Forward Euler does not preserve even the most basic properties of the solution. The uncertainty of a single parameter is a trivial problem compared to that. And now I would appreciate if you respected my decision to end this discussion. Everything of relevance has been said.

Comment: i am using approximation of the diode (that results in a different "sound", but people might not notice any difference) as an illustration.  other Runge-Kutta methods than a simple Euler (and i believe that i am using the backward Euler method which might be a little better than forward Euler) require iterations (like predictor-corrector) or intermediate calculations (to get you an idea), whereas the simple Euler methods just *eat* the error and march on.  it's not a homogeneous diff eq.  it's constantly driven by a varying non-zero input which sorta scrambles up quantization errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the approach you suggested because it gave me a good insight into how similar problems can be attacked and possibly solved. From engineering standpoint I'd agree with Robert - if it sounds good and doesn't "glitch" then it's good enough. I cannot think of any other numerical method that would be faster than Euler I (provided that Euler I will generate decent sound). The choice of the numerical method is just a detail for me because I can pick among many - what I really value about this answer is the approach presented as a whole. For me it's much simpler than i.e. WDF.

Answer (score 5):

One possible tool is [Wave Digital Filter analysis](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Wave_Digital_Filters_I.html) which is a type of physical modeling that represents signals as travelling waves. It can also be [extended to non-linear elements](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/WaveDigitalFilters/Nonlinear_Wave_Digital_Filters.html) such as diodes.

However, for distortion unit, you could instead of trying to digitalize the analog circuit try to extract a [waveshaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveshaper) from its behaviour. Common waveshapers are 3rd order polynomial and atan function.

**EDIT** : [here](http://legacy.spa.aalto.fi/dafx08/papers/dafx08_04.pdf) is an intersting paper about wave digital domain modeling of guitar distortion

**EDIT2** : and [here](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/files/dafx16_tutorial_macak.pdf) a DAFx lecture about existing methods for non linearities in virtual analog

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer! The waveshaping approach seems more practical for me, but there's still one problem I cannot figure out: Are there some general schemes I could use to derive waveshaping function for a circuit of for a frequency response of a circuit? I can imagine I could for example use a genetic algorithm to find polynomial coefficients for frequency response, but maybe there's some more deterministic way?

Comment: Well if your circuit is simply a distortion, you could find the caracteristic function (Vout = f(Vin) ) and then match a polynomial (or other forms). If it's a more complex circuit it might not be as "trivial"

Comment: Also I should warn you that obviously, waveshaping will introduce a lot of harmonics and will probably alias your signal... You could either take the easy way of "a distorted signal sounds harsh anyway so I don't mind", or you could oversample your signal to bandlimit it. Julius Orion Smith has an interesting chapter on non-linearities in his physical modeling book

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers! Now I will have a good bit of reading ahead! :)